# upload image in mysql database using php is not working correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, post

when I upload an image to MySQL database with other text fields I m getting a problem. The problem is that my text field data is inserting in another column and image file is inserting in another column while clicking the register button. Don't know what is the problem. Heres is mine code.

```
<?php 
// include 'connection.php';
ini_set('mysqli.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);






  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    }

      function fieldData(){
      $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','a.m.system');
        if(! $con ) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());}
    //setting field variables
      $fname = $_POST['first_name'];
      $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
       $gender = $_POST['gender'];
      $DOB = $_POST['dob'];
       $batch = $_POST['batch'];
      $address = $_POST['address'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
     $phone = $_POST['phone'];


     $sqlInsert="INSERT into students  
     (STD_First_Name,STD_Lastt_Name,STD_Gender,STD_DOB
      ,STD_Email,STD_Phone,STD_Address,STD_Batch) 

            VALUES ('$fname' , '$lname' , '$gender' ,'$DOB', '$email', 
      '$phone', '$address', '$batch') ";

         if (mysqli_query($con, $sqlInsert)) {
        $message = "Updated Successfully";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
         }else{
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error Inserting!!');
     </script>" . mysqli_error($con);
    }

    }
        if (getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == false) {
            echo "Please select an image!";
        }else{
            $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image = file_get_contents($image);
            $image = base64_encode($image);
            fieldData();
            saveImage($image);
        }

    //displayImage();
    //save image func
    function saveImage($image){
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','a.m.system');
        if(! $conn ) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());}
            $qry = " INSERT INTO students (STD_Image) values ('$image') ";
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
            if ($res) {
                echo "<br>Image Uploaded";
            }else{
                echo "<br>Image not Uploaded";
            }
    }


            mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

[image: This is the database snapshot.]

Comment: First, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider PDO or Prepared Statements. Second, you might have named the fields in HTML form incorrectly. Check that as we cannot since the code is not provided. Third, consider uploading an image physically rather than storing in the DB. This will eat your DB space for no reason.

Comment: I agree with Mohammed.  There are many issues with your code, on top of the question you asked.  In the interest of answering your question, I gave my below answer.  But, Mohammed's points are spot on, and should be considered on top of the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing two seperate inserts, is your issue.  So the first insert creates your user entry.  the second insert creates an empty record with just the image.

You need to refactor your code to either:

1) Change your second insert to an update statement.  You will need to pass the STD_ID to it (use the LAST_INSERT_ID() function to get the id after your first insert) and pass it to the saveImage() function.  While you're at it, pass $con as well, so you dont have to create another connection to the database.

2) Move all the code into one place.  Meaning, build out one insert statement including the image at the same time, so you dont need to do it twice.

There's a few more optimizations I'd make to your script, but the above items cover your question.

Comment: Thank you, bro, you saved my assignment. @R.Smith

Comment: Consider accepting the answer in case it has solved your problem. This is the proper way to close the question and pay respect to the person who answered.

Answer (score 0):

In simple , 
in the first query you have inserted the data in a row .
so,
You need to `UPDATE` the row for inserting the image .
but 
You used `INSERT` :(

Answer (score 0):

First upload photo in some directory of server. Then take image file in a variable like `$photo = "/photo/xyz.png"`

Add a field in `students` table for photo. Now your table structure contains following fields like `STD_First_Name, STD_Lastt_Name, STD_Gender,STD_DOB, STD_Email,STD_Phone,STD_Address,STD_Batch,photo`

```
$photo variable will be stored in `photo` field.
```

Never upload photo in database. Only store server's photo path in database.

***** My Suggestion : Use PDO instead of mysqli ****